# Error in Rhodes Application in Rhostudio

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I keep getting this error every now and then in my Rhodes app.
Using Rhostudio for development and this error comes in all applications,  on devices as well.

404 Not Found.

The action err_sync does not have a view or a controller

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you add the view and controller-action to your question along with how you call it ? If so I might be able to help.

Comment: when i run the application on simulator, it comes on every action. According to the log.. it comes as a result of sync action.

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring because of a bad URL. I have found that these types of errors can crop up unexpectedly and are very hard to pinpoint at times because often the URL of your request/page is changing due to the nature of navigation mechanisms in Rhodes.

I find using the Firebug plugin of Firefox to be VERY helpful when debugging my Rhodes app. You can hook it up very easily! You can load your app with any browser by configuring the web server to run on a specific port. This setting is in rhoconfig.txt and it is called local_server_port.

This is specifically helpful because you can easily survey the HTML and raw data of requests/responses, for example.